# Javascript, A sytax returns two different values?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Display the image the mouse hovers on, clearing the `<ul>`
But when I store the `src` *attribute* of the `<img>` in a
variable it returns two different `src`. Like src of the 
image , at the point and the modified one by the substring
Eg:

- //images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg
- //images/Hassum_Harrod.jpg

---

I want only a single output not two why does this happen please give a reason.

---

**Note**

- If `<img src="images/Hassum_Harrod_03_tn.jpg" />` **THUMBNAIL**
- If `<img src="images/Hassum_Harrod_03" />` **FULL IMAGE**

---

HTML CODE

```
<body>
  <div id="art">
  <h2>Art Preview</h2>
  <p>Mouse over the following pieces of art to preview a large version</p>
    <ul class="grid">
      <li><img src="images/Hassum_Harrod_03_tn.jpg" alt="Hassum Harod's Summer Trees"></li>
      <li><img src="images/LaVonne_LaRue_02_tn.jpg" alt="LaVonne_LaRue's Mighty Duck"></li>
      <li><img src="images/Lorenzo_Garcia_01_tn.jpg" alt="Lorenzo Garcia's The Dancer"></li>
                           <--FEW OTHER <li>'s-->
    </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
document.querySelector('.grid').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {

    ulNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

    var getAtt = e.target.getAttribute('src');
    var imgLoc = getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)+".jpg";
    console.log(imgLoc); //images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg
                        //images/Hassum_Harrod.jpg


    var createElement = document.createElement("img");
    createElement.setAttribute("src",imgLoc);
    ulNode.innerHTML="";
    ulNode.appendChild(createElement);

  } // check to see that I clicked on IMG only
}, false); // click event
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle by clicking on the Code Snippet button or pressing `Ctrl + M`?

Comment: Try logging `getAtt` variable. `getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)` will return `//images/Hassum_Harrod` with missing `_03.jpg`

Comment: Okay... Gimme a sec...

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: I cant put images in fiddle :(

Comment: @CoDINGinDARK use something like http://lorempixel.com/ for remote images

Comment: Same results if I log att 
images/Hassum_Harrod_03_tn.jpg
images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg

Comment: At least we can see the working script. Now we can't see anything right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you mouseover the "Hassum_Harrod_03_tn.jpg", the code:

```
getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)+".jpg"
```

should return the "images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg". However when it runs to:

```
var createElement = document.createElement("img");
createElement.setAttribute("src",getAtt + ".jpg");
ulNode.innerHTML="";
ulNode.appendChild(createElement);
```

The DOM was broken now as the "ul" element contains no "li" at all but an "img" in it.

Note the "mouseover" binding still works as the "ul" still lives.

Then a second mouseover on the "Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg" will get "Hassum_Harrod.jpg" and the "ulNode" in your code is no longer the "ul" but the upper "div" node. And the "mouseover" binding fails as no "ul" exists.

Comment: is `ul` broken because `ulNode.innerHTML` is set to blank ?

Comment: The DOM broke as the "ul" expects "li" as its children nodes.But in your case, the 2 times of calculation of  image src lead to the different "imgLoc". So it's better to check the img src was a real thumbnail first. e.g. var isThumbnail = getAtt.indexOf("_tn") !== -1; if (isThumbnail) { var imgLoc = getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)+".jpg"; ... }

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work!

```js
document.querySelector('.grid').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {

    ulNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

    var getAtt = e.target.getAttribute('src');
    var imgLoc = getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)+".jpg";
    console.log(imgLoc); //images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg
                        //images/Hassum_Harrod.jpg


    var createElement = document.createElement("img");
    createElement.setAttribute("src",getAtt + ".jpg");
    ulNode.innerHTML="";
    ulNode.appendChild(createElement);

  } // check to see that I clicked on IMG only
}, false); // click event
```

```html
<div id="art">
  <h2>Art Preview</h2>
  <p>Mouse over the following pieces of art to preview a large version</p>
  <ul class="grid">
    <li><img src="images/Hassum_Harrod_03_tn.jpg" alt="Hassum Harod's Summer Trees" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/LaVonne_LaRue_02_tn.jpg" alt="LaVonne_LaRue's Mighty Duck" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/Lorenzo_Garcia_01_tn.jpg" alt="Lorenzo Garcia's The Dancer" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The reason is, the `onMouseOver` event binds the image by changing it to the full version. That's the reason you get so.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because your are binding mouseover event for all img element (the one you created dynamically also) just check classname of  in mouseover function will work, I guess.

```
document.querySelector('.grid').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {

    ulNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
      if(ulNode.className == 'grid'){

    var getAtt = e.target.getAttribute('src');
    var imgLoc = getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)+".jpg";
    alert(imgLoc); //images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg
                        //images/Hassum_Harrod.jpg


    var createElement = document.createElement("img");
    createElement.setAttribute("src",imgLoc);
    ulNode.innerHTML="";
    ulNode.appendChild(createElement);
      }
  } // check to see that I clicked on IMG only
}, false); // click event
```

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector('.grid').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {

```
ulNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
ulNode.innerHTML="";
var getAtt = e.target.getAttribute('src');
var imgLoc = getAtt.substring(0,getAtt.length-7)+".jpg";
console.log(imgLoc); //images/Hassum_Harrod_03.jpg
                    //images/Hassum_Harrod.jpg


var createElement = document.createElement("img");
createElement.setAttribute("src",imgLoc);

ulNode.appendChild(createElement);
```

} // check to see that I clicked on IMG only
}, false); // click event

Comment: Move the ulNode.innerHTML=""; to top